# Vuetify RTL style

Tags: vue.js, textfield, right-to-left, vuetify.js

I am new to vuetify. I need rtl v-text-field with top-right caption on it. How is that possible? I could not do that in inspector. This what i have for a now:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hey @HoseinPanahi, if you found my answer helpful please mark it as the correct one, thanks :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Added features in v1.1.0:](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/internationalization#rtl)

> - Vuetify supports RTL (right to left) languages through the rtl prop during bootstrap. This value is dynamic and will apply custom styles to change the orientation of your components.

**To enable config level RTL support, add the `rtl` property to the Vuetify instance options:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  rtl: true
})
```

You can change this value anytime by directly modifying the `$vuetify.rtl` property from within your application.

Comment: required an edit!

Answer (score 4):

For Vue 2.x, the way to set RTL to true is [a bit different](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/rtl):

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  rtl: true,
})
```

or, as before, you can modify the rtl value on the vuetify object: `this.$vuetify.rtl = true`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the latest nuxt.js with `vuetify` you can add this in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
buildModules: [
  ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', { rtl: true }],
  ...
],
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no RTL support for vuetify right now.
but you can create your own CSS and change what you need.
first of all:
add dir=rtl to your app
and add this styles:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus, button:focus { outline: none !important; }

.list__tile__title {
    text-align: right;
}

.toolbar__title {
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.input-group--text-field label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    right: 0;
}

.input-group label {
    text-align: right;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
    transform-origin: top right;
}
.input-group.input-group--selection-controls label{
    right: 32px;
    left: auto;
}
.input-group.input-group--selection-controls .icon--selection-control {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
.input-group--selection-controls__ripple {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(12px,-52%,0);
    transform: translate3d(12px,-52%,0);
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

it's not complete. but fix some issues

Comment: what does dir=rtl do? What if I want to add custom styles to my datepicker component?

Comment: There is now :) it's been added in v1.1.0: https://libupdate.com/libs/38f99a55-a650-4d67-8e60-cd3c2737d043

Answer (score 2):

You should use `reverse` property for input components. Also, don't forget to change the text direction of input. Here is an example:

```css
input{
  direction: rtl;
}

.v-list-item__content{
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="4" right order="2">
              <v-select
                reverse
                outlined
                :items="drinks"
                label="نوشیدنی"
               >
               </v-select>
             </v-col>
             <v-col order="1">
              <v-text-field
                reverse outlined
                label="توضیحات"
                placeholder="شرایط نوشیدنی مطلوب شما"
              >
              </v-text-field>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: {
        drinks: ['چای', 'قهوه']
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually this is a better way than changing the entire app's direction to RTL

Answer (score 1):

The following example demonstrates how to force RTL for a specific section of your content, without switching the current language, by using the `v-locale-provider` component:

```
<v-app>
  <v-card>...</v-card> <!-- default locale used here -->

  <v-locale-provider rtl>
    <v-card>...<v-card> <!-- default locale used here, but with RTL active -->
  </v-locale-provider>
</v-app>
```

**For example:**

```
<v-locale-provider rtl>
          <v-select
            reverse
            outlined
            :items="drinks"
            label="نوشیدنی"
           >
           </v-select>
</v-locale-provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use text-right class for an element or a container tag

```
<p class="text-right">این متن فارسی است</p>
```

for more information you can visit this link
[rtl-alignment](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/#rtl-alignment)